# Как записать id дочерней категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть такой код

```html
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => 4, 'orderby' => 'id')); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $child) { ?>

<?php $categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => 14, 'orderby' => 'id', 'hide_empty' => 0)); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $child) { ?>

<?php } ?>


<?php } ?>
```

Как записать вместо статического номера категории (14) его id динамически, чтобы это работало для всех подкатегорий?

В категории 4 есть подкатегории 5-6-7-8-9-10, в категории 7 есть подкатегории 14-15. Я вывожу список категорий и когда нужно список их подкатегорий

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что вам нужно вывести древо категорий?

Comment: Да, у меня выводится цикл из категорий и в одной категории выводится цикл из подкатегорий, но я записываю эти подкатегории через id, а мне хотелось бы, чтобы этот id брался из родительской категории

категории
— подкатегории

Comment: Сперва нужно получить массив всех родительских категорий, а потом пройтись по нему и вывести дочерние. Для получения родителей можно использовать get_categories() с параметром hierarchical => false